# I use virtualDisplay to mirror screen on android phone,how can I changge the framerate to 90?

Tags: frame-rate, mirror, surfaceflinger

I use virtualDisplay to mirror screen on android phone,how can I changge the framerate to 90?

I guess maybe I should modify the code in surfaceflinger or some where,but I don't know,I need help,thanks!!!

Comment: SurfaceFlinger bases its timing on the refresh rate of the primary display, which is usually 60 fps. Mirroring at a higher rate wouldn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Beyond that, you cannot modify `surfaceflinger`, unless you are building your own custom ROM, AFAIK.